# Inno Setup: Populating VersionInfoDescription and VersionInfoCopyright from an INI file using Pascal Scripting (scripted constant) setup property

Tags: inno-setup

I have a little problem with Inno Setup regarding the "Window" property of the Setup.exe. This is the problem that I have:

[image: Setup property page]

In the property of the setup, under the *Detail* tab, I see that the description and the copyright haven't the right information.

This is what I use in Inno Setup this to allow user to customize the installer:

```
[Setup]
VersionInfoDescription={code:GetAppName} {code:GetVersion}
VersionInfoCopyright={code:GetPublisher}
```

During the installer this field are correctly fill with the right information (that I load in a .ini file).

So, the question is:

Does anyone know how to fill correctly this field in the property of the installer and and still let users to customize the installer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VersionInfoDescription` and `VersionInfoCopyright` cannot contain constants (like `{code:...}`)

But if you use the Pascal Scripting to load an INI file only, you can use preprocessor instead:

```
VersionInfoDescription={#ReadIni("C:\path\test.ini", "Section", "Name")}
```

See a documentation for [`ReadIni`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=readini).

Comment: So VersionInfoDescription and VersionInfoCopyright cannot be dynamic, right? But there are set only in compiling time?

Comment: Correct, they have to be set at compile-time.